# TinyMCE 4 Table resize cells by dragging

Tags: tinymce-4

I was looking for a TinyMCE plugin for table resize cell by dragging and I came to:
http://sourceforge.net/p/tinymce/plugins/163/?page=2

Here there is a working example http://tinymcesupport.com/premium-plugins/resize-table-cells

Unfortunately this is for an old version (I'm using the 4) and also following the migration guide I didn't came to a working version.

I'm not a Java programmer and I don't know if the migration is quite simple with some small changes or more development is necessary.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TinyMCE now supports resizing columns with [its 4.3 release](https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/changelog/#version430-november232015). Simply enable the table plugin as shown:

```js
tinymce.init({
  inline: true,
  selector: 'table',
  plugins: 'table'
});
```

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  
}

th, td {
  border: solid 1px #ccc;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="//cdn.tinymce.com/4/tinymce.min.js"></script>

Make sure the <code>table</code> plugin is activated, then drag the columns to resize them:

<table style="width: 100%;">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Column 1</th>
      <th>Column 2</th>
      <th>Column 3</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
      <tr>
      <td>Data</td>
      <td>Data</td>
      <td>Data</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: They moved their blog to a new domain and that post doesn't exist anymore. Link updated to point to the 4.3 changelog.